# Toggle search highlight while on match

Tags: search

I'd like to have search highlights (`set hlsearch`) while the cursor is on a match and to turn it off automatically (`set nohlsearch`) when I move the cursor away.

Example:

```
foo bar foo
text text bar
```

After searching for bar: while the cursor is on "bar" the highlight is on, when the cursor moves away to "foo" or "text" the highlight is off and goes back on when I `n`/`N`/return to "bar".

---

I found a search "hack" in this [plugin](https://github.com/romainl/vim-cool/blob/master/plugin/cool.vim) and used it with @Tumbler41's idea:

```
:autocmd CursorMoved * if (search('\%#\zs'.@/,'cnW',line('.'))) | set hlsearch | else | set nohlsearch | endif
```

Only highlights when I'm on the first char but that's fine for me.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in vanilla vim. A plugin should be able to do it though if you don't mind acting every time the cursor moves ([`:help CursorMoved`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#CursorMoved))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually a lot simpler than I originally thought, try this `autocmd` and see if it does what you're looking for:

```
autocmd CursorMoved * if (expand('<cword>') =~ @/) | set hlsearch | else | set nohlsearch | endif
```

This looks at the current word under the cursor and compares it the the search register (`@/`). If it matches, the command sets `hlsearch`, otherwise it unsets it.

Comment: Thanks, thas a great idea and it works for my example but not when I search for two words ...

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. This only looks at a single word under the cursor. I can't put more effort into this right now, but I'll think about it and update later if I come up with a better solution.

Comment: OK, thanks anyways! I know that `synID()` allows to get a syntax ID for the specified position - anyone know if there is something similar for the highlight?

Comment: Found something - see update.